# Spatially dissolve lines that intersect, after attending tabular conditions

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I need to dissolve all Linestrings from a `geodataframe` that intersect each other after attending some tabular conditions: 1)have the same `ID` and 2) have the same `opening` year. The data represent a road database and I am working with `geopandas`. The data look like this:

```
    id    opening    geometry
0   30    2020       LINESTRING (45.01679 -12.12937, 45.01681 -12...
1   101   1999       LINESTRING (37.02849 -10.65968, 37.02849 -10...
2   30    2019       LINESTRING (47.10667 -15.49339, 47.10665 -15...
3   101   1999       LINESTRING (41.64170 -12.45764, 41.64180 -12...
4   135   2020       LINESTRING (45.31902 -9.76800, 45.31907 -9.7...
```

I have tried the following code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import shapely

gdf_sof = gpd.read_file('your_path/your_file')

# Concatenate the conected segments
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
for id in gdf_sof.id.unique():
  print(id)
  unique_id = gdf_sof.loc[gdf_sof.id == id]
  print(unique_id.shape)
  gdf_sof_id = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
  for dt in unique_id.opening.unique():
    print(dt)
    unique_oppening = unique_id.loc[unique_id.opening == dt]
    dissolved = gpd.geoseries.GeoSeries([geom for geom in unique_oppening.unary_union.geoms])
    gdf_sof_id = pd.concat([gdf_sof_id, dissolved], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
  gdf.concat(gdf_sof_id, ignore_index=True, axis=0, inplace=True)

gdf.shape
```

But got this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: 'LineString' object has no attribute 'geoms'
```

I also tried the following code based on @Pieter's comment, but the result isn't satisfactory. I used both `linemerge` and `shapely.get_parts`.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import shapely
from shapely.ops import linemerge

gdf_sof = gpd.read_file('your_path/your_file')

# Dissolve the connected segments
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
for id in gdf_sof.id.unique():
  unique_id = gdf_sof.loc[gdf_sof.id == id]
  gdf_sof_id = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
  for dt in unique_id.opening.unique():
    unique_opening = unique_id.loc[unique_id.opening == dt]
    shp = shapely.get_parts(unique_opening.geometry)
    dissolved = linemerge(shp)
    gdf_dissolved = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'id': [id],
                                      'opening': [dt],
                                      'geometry':dissolved},
                                      geometry = 'geometry', 
                                      crs = gdf_sof.crs)
    gdf_sof_id = pd.concat([gdf_sof_id, gdf_dissolved], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
  gdf = pd.concat([gdf, gdf_sof_id], ignore_index=True, axis=0)

gdf.shape
```

My starting gdf (`gdf_sof`) has the shape `(7366, 3)`, and the final `gdf` has a shape of `(973, 3)`. However, the final gdf `(973,3)` dissolved segments that don't touch.

[image: All selected segments in the image are just one row in the attribute table. I need them separated!]

All selected segments in the image above are just one row in the attribute table. I need them separated!

Comment: To merge lines, please use the [linemerge](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.linemerge) function instead of `unary_union`. The error signifies that the geometry you use the `geoms` property on isn't a multi-geometry, so you will have to check that before you call geoms, or you can use [shapely.get_parts](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.get_parts.html)